# Franz taking up over 100% CPU/Killing battery

Tags: battery, cpu-load, franz

I installed Franz messenger from [here on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/jamiesoncj/756728b3ba7c07d7a90f843400af37bb)

At the bottom the last comment is how I did it.

Its installed and working but keeps using over 100% CPU.

From `top` I get,

```
1768 savellm   20   0 1581140 113316  72904 R 105.0  0.7  12:24.70 Franz
```

Did I install this correctly? And is there any way to fix it, as I'm pretty sure it shouldn't use all that CPU?